# Use git alias with argument

Tags: git

I do this command a lot

```
git merge --no-ff --no-commit SomeBranch
```

I tried to make an alias

```
git config alias.nff "merge --no-ff --no-commit $1"
```

and use it

```
git nff SomeBranch
```

But I got and error and saw this in my config file

```
[alias]
    nff = "merge --no-ff --no-commit "
```

So I changed it to

```
    nff = "merge --no-ff --no-commit $1"
```

However I still get an error when I run the command

```
$ git nff SomeBranch
fatal: $1 - not something we can merge
```

Why is it using $1 instead of my argument? And how might I set it via command like (i had to add $1 by hand in the config file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need $1

```
git config alias.nff "merge --no-ff --no-commit"
```

Will do the trick

```
git nff SomeBranch
```

expands to

```
git merge --no-ff --no-commit SomeBranch
```

Answer (score 0):

Fist idea that come in my head it's write bat files for all commands that u use, put them in  separate folder and path to this folder to you `PATH` variable.

i'm not sure that this is a good way, but i only say my idea about that.